# Extract proper HTML document from PDF with Apache Tika

Tags: html, xml, python-2.7, pdf, apache-tika

I would like to extract content from PDF file. I'm using Apache Tika 1.15 as a command line tool called from Python script.

The problem I found in extracted XML content is that it is represented mostly as HTML paragraph tags.

Is it possible to extract such content with valid HTML tags: `<h1>`, `<strong>`, etc? If no, do you have any experience with other tools with better results?

I have searched here for various tools and it's quite huge list of them - unfotunately experimenting with each will be a timewaste.

Comment: Are you aware of how the PDF format works? And how that kind of semantic information is generally not present.... Any chance you could extract from the original Word / RTF / etc formats instead of the PDF?

Comment: To be honest I didn't search anything about PDF format and it's semamtic. PDF's are from around the world and usually unfortunately are not available in other formats.